# Windows 10 crash when application calls null address, how to fix?

Tags: windows-10, crash, debug

I am using Windows 10. It was upgraded from Windows 8. I recently did a PC reset and also did a reinstall of all drivers; however I am still experiencing crashes when running applications, especially games.

I tried this with multiple games that crash the PC and always got the same "Exception Thrown" message:

I launch a game and immediately go to Task Manager and right click on the application, selecting "Debug". This opens up Visual Studio to debug the application. I then keep playing the game and this time, instead of the PC crashing, I get a message like this:

```
Exception thrown at 0x02887BB6 in MidBoss.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation 
reading location 0x00000000.
```

I did this with multiple games and I always get this message, but with different memory addresses. In each case it tries reading a null address. If I'm not debugging at the time this happens, the PC crashes and restarts.

Since I obviously don't have have the source code for these games and am only debugging the application's executable, I don't know what how to diagnose the problem.

Visual Studio gives me option to view the assembly code for what happened, but I have no idea what to make of it. Here 's the assembly for what caused the crash last time:

```
02887BB6  cmp         byte ptr [edi],al
```

I have no idea what to make of this. What should I do?

Comment: Try to open Command Prompt as administrator and run `sfc /scannow`. If this issue is caused by broken system files, this should fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, bu that doesn't fix it.